# remove double quotes from json string using sed

Tags: linux

I am trying to remove double quotes from a string using this command but the sed always adds the quotes, not sure what's wrong with this.

```
value = ["some_json_object"]
```

json string passing in as new_value:

```
"{\"new_name\":\"foo\",\"value\":\"bar\"}"

sed -i -e "s/some_json_object/jsondecode($new_value)/"
```

output:

```
["jsondecode({"new_name":"foo","value":"bar"})"]
```

expected_output:

```
[jsondecode({"new_name":"foo","value":"bar"})]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` didn't add the quotes, they're in the original file and you don't remove them. Include them in the pattern you're replacing.

```
sed -i -e "s/\"some_json_object\"/jsondecode($new_value)/"
```